# emacs shell mode input buffer size

Tags: emacs

There is a problem with shell mode and comint.el described in [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2006-09/msg00007.html) bug report when entering long lines. I tried to change the TERM env variable settings to emacs but it didn't fix the problem. Any clue where I should look in comint.el?

Comment: What Emacs version, on what operating system? What makes you think that the limitation comes from Emacs and not from the interpreter? What is the interpreter, and have you tried with others?

Comment: I've tried to copy the same line to the interpreter outside of emacs and it works fine. I have emacs 23.1.1 on linux x86_64 redhat 6.4. Isn't there a variable in the shell mode to set the input line size?

Comment: There's no such thing as “the input line size”, so no. Shell mode sends lines one at a time regardless of their length. This looks like a defect in the interpreter where it is buggy when it receives too much input at once. Once again, what is the interpreter?

Comment: kdb q. I tried to copy the same line outside of emacs and it works.

Comment: Maybe there's a special character copied and pasted that emacs will interpret as a return and the interpreter not ? Did you try typing in a long line ?

Comment: It might have to do with the copy&paste buffer. I tried to type a line of more than 500 characters and the interpreter worked fine. It might actually be related to my X server, or maybe the emacs clipboard?

Comment: @Gilles It seems to be related to comint.el. See my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd encountered this in the past and the following piece of [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) works well for me:

```
(defadvice process-send-string (around process-send-string-in-chunks act)
  "break the string to be sent into chunks
This avoids some bug when sending long strings that causes a
^D character to be inserted.  Breaking the string into chunks that
are 200 chars long (arbitrary value) avoids the problem."
  (let ((str (ad-get-arg 1))
        substr
        (chunk-len 200))
    (while (> (length str) 0)
      (setq substr (substring str 0 (min (length str) chunk-len)))
      (ad-set-arg 1 substr)
      ad-do-it
      (setq str (substring str (length substr) (length str))))))
```

It solves the problem by breaking the string into 200 character chunks.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across this limitation in shell mode... in my case, the problem was related to shell-mode appending `--noediting` when the shell is 'bash' (/bin/sh doesn't receive this argument).

The `--noediting` arg (same as `set +o emacs +o vi` in bash) meant bash wasn't using readline to process input and had some internal buffer-size limitation. To reproduce outside emacs, start `bash --noediting -i` and then just start typing... after some limit (1024 characters in my case), the input is just blocked...

Additionally, bash internally disables editing if TERM is "emacs" or "dumb", so the TERM entry needs to be something else (I chose "xterm", you could use "ansi" or "vt100" too)

The easy workaround for .emacs is:

```
    (setq explicit-bash-args '("-i"))
    (setq comint-terminfo-terminal "xterm")
```

NOTE: you can't use shell-mode-hook as it runs after bash-args is used.

This does break tab-completion, and may break with colorized prompts or similar edge cases, but I can finally paste my insanely long compile lines without the shell rejecting them.  You may find a need to run 'set -o emacs' (or vi) from time to time, as some actions seem to reset noediting...

Comment: You might try experimenting with `process-connection-type` being set to `nil` when the process is started, in order to use a pipe rather than a pty.  A pty will be in canonical / line-editing mode by default ("stty -F <device> -icanon" to disable that).  That provides line-discipline support for certain line-editing key sequences, and also imposes a maximum input size for any line (4096 bytes in my tests), discarding the overflow.  Using a pipe instead of a pty avoids this 4K buffer issue, as well as any other terminal-oriented behaviours.  (Which is probably *bad* for a shell, but YMMV.)

Comment: Interesting suggestion, however in the case of shell-mode, setting this resulted in ```Process shell stopped (tty input): 21```